Getting rows with different data between dataframes
I'm in the process of learning pandas and as a beginner I'm amazed by some of its capabilities. I'm currently trying to compare two dataframes and extract the rows of one dataframe that contain different data from the other. Some of the data in the row may be the same, some may be different. But if it isn't 100% identical, I need to extract it and put it into a new dataframe.
Here is the solution that I have:
before = [["Tyler", 4000, "Florida"], ["Kwon", 2500, "Missouri"], ["Yoshi", 1900, "Hawaii"], ["Richard", 5600, "New York"]]
beforedf = pd.DataFrame(before, columns=["Name", "Balance", "Location"])


after = [["Tyler", 4000, "Virginia"], ["Kwon", 2600, "Missouri"], ["Yoshi", 1200, "Texas"], ["Richard", 5600, "New York"]]
afterdf = pd.DataFrame(after, columns=["Name", "Balance", "Location"])

result = []
for i in range(len(beforedf)):
    if not beforedf.iloc[i].equals(afterdf.iloc[i]):
        holder = beforedf.loc[i, :].values.flatten().tolist()
        result.append(holder)

I can then create a new dataframe using the data from result which is a list of lists. I just think that there is a better way to go about this, but I'm having trouble finding it. I've done some research and have seen suggestions for .isin(), but this doesn't seem to apply to rows who share at least some similar data. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

Another possible solution, which uses merge. The left join option indicates (as indicator=True) the rows in beforedf that are only in beforedf (left_only and not in both dataframes):
beforedf[
    beforedf.merge(
        afterdf, on=beforedf.columns.to_list(),
        how='left', indicator=True)['_merge']
    .eq('left_only')]

Output:
    Name  Balance  Location
0  Tyler     4000   Florida
1   Kwon     2500  Missouri
2  Yoshi     1900    Hawaii


One way to handle this is using the .compare() DataFrame method: DataFrame.compare()
Using your dataframe examples above:
before = [["Tyler", 4000, "Florida"], ["Kwon", 2500, "Missouri"], ["Yoshi", 1900, "Hawaii"], ["Richard", 5600, "New York"]]
beforedf = pd.DataFrame(before, columns=["Name", "Balance", "Location"])


after = [["Tyler", 4000, "Virginia"], ["Kwon", 2600, "Missouri"], ["Yoshi", 1200, "Texas"], ["Richard", 5600, "New York"]]
afterdf = pd.DataFrame(after, columns=["Name", "Balance", "Location"])

We call the compare() method on one of the DataFrames like so:
resultdf = beforedf.compare(afterdf, align_axis=0, keep_equal=True)
resultdf

This gives us a DataFrame of each row that is different:
          Balance   Location
0   self    4000      Florida
    other   4000      Virginia
1   self    2500      Missouri
    other   2600      Missouri
2   self    1900      Hawaii
    other   1200      Texas

This works if you're trying to get a DataFrame of all rows that aren't exact matches to one another. See the documentation for other options that the .compare() method has.

you could compare the dataframes element-wise and check if all elements in each row are identical.
before = [["Tyler", 4000, "Florida"], ["Kwon", 2500, "Missouri"], ["Yoshi", 1900, "Hawaii"], ["Richard", 5600, "New York"]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(before, columns=["Name", "Balance", "Location"])


after = [["Tyler", 4000, "Virginia"], ["Kwon", 2600, "Missouri"], ["Yoshi", 1200, "Texas"], ["Richard", 5600, "New York"]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(after, columns=["Name", "Balance", "Location"])

rows_not_identical = ~(df1 == df2).all(axis=1)
result_df = df1[rows_not_identical]

print(result_df)

  Name  Balance  Location
0  Tyler     4000   Florida
1   Kwon     2500  Missouri
2  Yoshi     1900    Hawaii

